# FB init function is not working in angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook, sdk, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have tried many solutions For below mentioned error but nothing works for me I have refereed "https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/howto/angularjs" for my implementation.

"Error: FB is not defined"

I am sharing my code below for controller and service files.

## socialMedia.js -Controller

```
'use strict';
app
.controller('SocialMediaController', [
  '$rootScope', '$scope', '$location', '$cookieStore' , 'SocialMedia', 'ngToast','$window',
        function ($rootScope, $scope, $location, $cookieStore, SocialMedia, ngToast,$window) {

        $window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({ 
              appId: '************',
              status: true, 
              cookie: true, 
              xfbml: true,
              version: 'v2.4'
            });
        };

        // Load the SDK asynchronously
        (function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

        $scope.testAPI = function() {
            SocialMedia.getMyLastName() 
             .then(function(response) {
               $scope.last_name = response.last_name;
            }
            );
        };

  }
]);
```

## socialMedia.js -Services

```
   'use strict';
app
.factory('SocialMedia', [
    '$http', '$cookieStore', '$rootScope', 'appApi', function ($http, $cookieStore, $rootScope, appApi) {

        return {
            getMyLastName: function() {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                FB.api('/me', {
                    fields: 'last_name'
                }, function(response) {
                    if (!response || response.error) {
                        deferred.reject('Error occured');
                    } else {
                        deferred.resolve(response);
                    }
                });
                return deferred.promise;
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

## Html file

```
<input type="button" ng-click="testAPI()" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary md-trigger" />
```

Let me konw where I am wrong in this.

Comment: just make sure that you are using FB.api AFTER FB.init. i assume your socialMedia service is calling FB.api before that. i see no login functionality either, btw. so /me will not work anyway.

Comment: maybe this helps you a bit: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Answer (score 0):

Call your FB functions after the SDK is loaded asynchronously, Otherwise it will throw that "FB is not defined".

Put this code out side of AngularJs script.

```
// Load the SDK asynchronously
(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[   
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Code didn't test please test and update back.

Answer (score -1):

**Try removing**

`'use strict';`

When u use that , you always have to declare FB before you use it. 
removing it use strict i think that you can solve this issue.

It is the best solution that i know.

Thank You
Chathula

Comment: sorry, but that´s completely wrong: https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode